# Can Mockito verify parameters based on their values at the time of method call?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I have a `Foo` class which is SUT and a `Bar` class, which is its collaborator. `Foo` calls `run(List<Object> values)` on the `Bar` with "`expectedList`" as an argument. Then, `Foo` will add a few more elements to this `List` so that its state will be different from what it was at the time of calling `run()`. Here's my test case.

```
@Test
public void testFoo() {
    Bar collaborator = spy(new Bar()); 
    Foo sut = new Foo(collaborator);
    verify(collaborator).run(expectedList);
}
```

Note that the collaborator is actually a spy object rather than a mock. This test case will fail because even though `run()` was called with an argument equal to `expectedList`, it was modified since and its current value no longer equals `expectedList`. However, this is the way it is supposed to work, so I'm wondering if there's a way to have Mockito store the snapshot of parameters when a method is called and verify them based on these values rather than the most recent values.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use an `Answer` to check the value of the argument when the method is called.  You can either throw an `AssertionError` within the `Answer` if the value is wrong, or you can store the value, and do your assertion at the end.

Comment: Yeah David is right. Due the way the Mockito's API is crafted it is not possible to verify multiple calls with the same argument reference. EasyMock can do that because it has an expectation phase before production code is ran. Anyway instead of an `Answer` I use an `ArgurmentCaptor` and write one or more assertions on the final state of that list, i.e. with FEST-Assert `assertThat(captor.getValue()).contains("A", "B").contains("T", "U");`

Comment: @Brice - how would that work any differently from Michael Wiles' approach?

Comment: It isn't. It's just a different way of achieving the test purpose. Because most of the time you don't really need to check intermediate arguments, but just that some interactions happened and the final result. Though I must say if Tom had specific requirement then agreed this won't help him, but then in this case I would avoid mutable objects in my production code. It feels like messaging between two collaborators and messages should always be immutable.

Comment: @Brice, when verifying the arguments passed to the mock, it seems logically incorrect to match the final state of the instance, since that was not the state at the time of the mock interaction.

Comment: @NieldeWet Yes indeed, that's the whole point of immutability of the _message_ between two collaborators ;)

Comment: Example possible please?  For followers, there is a slightly different example bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51547452/how-do-i-use-mockito-argument-capture-to-verify-value-of-property-within-object?noredirect=1#comment90161506_51547452

Answer (score 1):

[The answer of Dawood ibn Kareem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089145/1020871) worked for me but I lacked an example, also I use Kotlin and [Mockito-Kotlin](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin), so my solution is like this:

```
class Foo(var mutable: String)

interface Bar {
    fun run(foo: Foo)
}

@Test fun `validate mutable parameter at invocation`() {
    val bar = mock<Bar>()

    var valueAtInvocation: String? = null
    whenever(bar.run(any())).then {
        val foo = it.arguments.first() as Foo
        valueAtInvocation = foo.mutable // Store mutable value as it was at the invocation
        Unit // The answer
    }

    val foo = Foo(mutable = "first")
    bar.run(foo)
    valueAtInvocation isEqualTo "first"

    foo.mutable = "second"
    bar.run(foo)
    valueAtInvocation isEqualTo "second"
}
```

`valueAtInvocation` will represent the value of the mutable property `foo.mutable` at the last invocation of `bar.run(foo)`. Should also be possible to do assertions within the `then {}` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `verify()` on an object that is not a `mock`.  Is this what you meant?

```
Bar collaborator = mock(Bar.class); 
Foo sut = spy(new Foo(collaborator));
verify(collaborator).run(expectedList);
```

Comment: Thanks, the example code had an error and I corrected it. That's not my question though. It's about being able to verify an argument based on its value at the time of the method call, not the most recent one.

Answer (score -3):

Why don't you try using argument capture to acquire the value of expected list when it was run and then you can compare it.

```
ArgumentCaptor<List> listCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(List.class);

verify(collaborator).run(listCaptor.capture());

assertEquals(expectedList, argument.getValue());
```

Comment: If your modified list is the same instance, then argument.getValue() will return the `expectedList` instance, not a copy, so this is essentially the same as he's doing, isn't it?

Comment: @Michael Wiles Thanks, but as jhericks mentioned, the ArgumentCaptor captures the original List instance.

Comment: Sorry, Michael, I downvoted your answer because your solution has exactly the same problem as the OP's test, as explained by jhericks.