# Mockito Verify: Verified during verify() than during mocked method call

Tags: java, junit, mockito, verify

I call a method performAction with list of objects and verify the same. After this method is called, I modify some of the "objects".

Mockito verify fails saying that arguments don't match (showing modified objects) but I can see in debug mode that objects were correct as needed.

Ideally, this should not happen as verify should be applied on the basis of when method was actually called. Does verify apply during verify call in test method than at the time of mocked method call?

Test Class

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    List<ABC> objects = new ArrayList<ABC>();
    //populate objects.
    activity.performActions(objects);               
    verify(activity, times(1)).doActivity(objects);
}
```

Method to test:

```
public void performActions(List<ABC> objects) {

    activity.doActivity(urlObjects2PerformAction);
    //Modify objects                

}
```

Error I am getting is as follows (this is for complete code. I have given smallest possible snippet):

```
Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
activity.doActivity(
.......
......
```

Comment: Reduce the code to the shortest example that reproduces the problem, paste the complete code of this example, and the exact and complete error message you get.

Comment: @JBNizet Modified the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This has been asked before - at [Can Mockito verify parameters based on their values at the time of method call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085738/can-mockito-verify-parameters-based-on-their-values-at-the-time-of-method-call/9089145)

When you call a method that has been stubbed with Mockito, Mockito will store the arguments that are passed to it, so that you can use `verify` later.  That is, it stores object references, not the contents of the objects themselves.  If you later change the contents of those objects, then your `verify` call will compare its arguments to the updated objects - it doesn't make a deep copy of the original objects.

If you need to verify what the contents of the objects were, you'll need to EITHER

- store them yourself at the time of the method call; OR
- verify them at the time of the method call.

The right way to do either of these is with a Mockito `Answer`.  So, for the second option, you would create an `Answer` that does the verification, and throws an `AssertionFailedError` if the argument values are incorrect; instead of using `verify` at the end of the test.

Answer (score 1):

`verify` compares the parameter contents at the time `verify` is called and not when the mocked method is called. If the contents of the list is modified then `verify` will use the modified values.

An alternative is to use an `Answer` instead to check the parameters as soon as the method is called, or you can create a new list instead of modifying the old one.

Answer (score 0):

this can be solved now using ArgumentCaptor

```
@Test
public void test() throws Exception {
    List<ABC> objects = new ArrayList<ABC>();
    ArgumentCaptor<List<ABC> objectsCaptor = ArgumentCaptor<List.class>;
    //populate objects.
    activity.performActions(objects);               
    verify(activity, times(1)).doActivity(objectsCaptor.capture());
}
```

Comment: What Java do you use? It seems that the answer doesn't work for `Java 8`, at least, for complex object.