# Mockito verify with list that changes

Tags: java, list, collections, mockito

I've got a simple `Bar` that does an action on some Strings:

```
public interface Bar {

  void action(List<String> strings);

}
```

And then my `Foo` which is under test. It builds up a list of Strings over time, and then eventually uses `Bar` to process them. When they've been processed, the queue is cleared.

```
public class Foo {

  private final Bar bar;
  private final List<String> strings;

  public Foo(Bar bar) {
    this.bar = bar;
    this.strings = new ArrayList<>();
  }

  public void addStrings(String... strings) {
      Collections.addAll(this.strings, strings);
  }

  public void processStrings() {
    bar.action(strings);
    strings.clear();
  }

}
```

I am trying to verify that the `Bar.action` gets called with the expected Strings. However, Mockito doesn't detect the true invocation with the actual parameters, because the list that *was* used when invoking `Bar.action` gets cleared afterwards.

I might be doing something wrong, but this smells like a bug to me. Here's the test:

```
@Test
public void shouldVerify() {
    // Given
    Bar bar = mock(Bar.class);
    Foo foo = new Foo(bar);
    foo.addStrings("Hello", "World");
    foo.addStrings("!!!");
    // When
    foo.processStrings();
    // Then
    verify(bar).action(Arrays.asList("Hello", "World", "!!!"));
}
```

> Comparison Failure:
>
> Expected :bar.action([Hello, World, !!!]);
>
> Actual   :bar.action([]);

To be sure, commenting out `strings.clear()` lets Mockito verify correctly.

---

I can get around this by making a new list to pass to `Bar`, e.g.:

```
public void processStrings() {
  bar.action(new ArrayList<>(strings));
  strings.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Not totally sure here, but this seems to be a limitation of Mockito (but don't quote me on that). At first I thought this could be solved with an `ArgumentCaptor` but it captures the same instance and when you verify it, it has already been modified.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9089145/2928051) you could use an `Answer` to verify the argument when the method is called. Since `Bar::action` has a return type of void, stubbing it requires a slightly different approach. [Mockito docs](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.22/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer(org.mockito.stubbing.Answer)) suggest to use the `doX()` family of methods.

```
public void name() {
    Bar bar = mock(Bar.class);
    doAnswer(invocation -> {
        Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
        List<String> list = (List<String>) args[0];
        assertThat(list.size(), is(3));
        return null;
    }).when(bar).action(anyList());

    Foo foo = new Foo(bar);
    foo.addStrings("Hello", "World");
    foo.addStrings("!!!");
    foo.processStrings();
}
```

In the `doAnswer` block you have access to the list when it was passed to the mock. Assertions could be done there or you could store the argument and do them later. I would say that the solution is not very elegant though.