# How do I use Mockito Argument Capture to verify value of property within object passed to mocked method?

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm new at using mockito and I'm having difficulty in verifying the properties of an object that I'm sending to a mocked method.

Here's the interface of the method I'm mocking...

```
public interface OrderDAO {    
  int update(Order order) throws SQLException;    
}
```

Here's the method within my Order class that I'm testing...

```
public boolean cancelOrder(int id) throws OrderDataStoreException {    
  try {
    Order orderToCancel = dao.read(id);
    orderToCancel.setStatus("cancelled");        
    int result = dao.update(orderToCancel);
    if (result == 0) {            
           return false;        
    }    
  } catch (SQLException ex) {        
      throw new OrderDataStoreException(ex);    
  }    
return true;
}
```

Here's the Junit Test using Fluent Assertions...

```
@Test
public void cancelOrder_ShouldNot_SetOrderStatusToCancel() throws SQLException, OrderDataStoreException {


  Order order = OrderHelper.createSimpleOrder(4); //creates order with "New" status

  when(mockOrderDAO.read(order.getId())).thenReturn(order);
  when(mockOrderDAO.update(any(Order.class))).thenReturn(0);

  boolean result = serviceUnderTest.cancelOrder(order.getId());


  assertThat(result).isFalse();
  assertThat(order.getStatus()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("cancelled"); //verify the ending status is "cancelled"
  verify(mockOrderDAO).read(4);

  //here we create the orderArg. I've defined it in the arrange area.
  ArgumentCaptor<Order> orderArg = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Order.class);

  //here we capture that argument we sent
  verify(mockOrderDAO).update(orderArg.capture());

  assertThat(orderArg.getValue().getStatus()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("cancelled");
  assertThat(orderArg.getValue().getId()).isEqualTo(4);   

  }
```

This test passes, since the status property of the orderArg is set to "cancelled". However this test still passes if I simply move flip a couple of lines...

```
int result = dao.update(orderToCancel);
orderToCancel.setStatus("cancelled");
```

I would expect this to fail, since at the time dao.update was called the status of orderToCancel was "New".

Any help would be appreciated.

After a report of this being a duplicate of another question I was able to resolve my unit test issue. Here is what I was able to work out.

```
@Test
public void cancelOrder_Should_CallDAOToUpdateToCancelledStatus() throws SQLException, OrderDataStoreException {


Order order = OrderHelper.createSimpleOrder(4);
when(mockOrderDAO.read(order.getId())).thenReturn(order);

when(mockOrderDAO.update(any(Order.class))).thenAnswer(
    VerifyOrderState(4, "cancelled")
);

boolean result = serviceUnderTest.cancelOrder(order.getId());

assertThat(result).isFalse();
assertThat(order.getStatus()).isEqualToIgnoringCase("cancelled");
verify(mockOrderDAO).read(4);
}

private Answer VerifyOrderState(final int expectedId, final String expectedStatus) {
return new Answer() {
  public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
    Object[] state = invocation.getArguments();
    Order orderWhenUpdated = (Order)state[0];
    assertThat(orderWhenUpdated.getStatus()).isEqualToIgnoringCase(expectedStatus);
    assertThat(orderWhenUpdated.getId()).isEqualTo(expectedId);

    return null;
  }
};
```

}

Comment: reference to the other article and some more digging I figured out a solution for my example.

Comment: Yeah different question but the answers "tend to be the same" so the recommended approach is to close as duplicate, even though it's not the same question.  FWIW :)